# Error: cannot find automatically a registry where to push images - Kamel Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-camel, dockerfile

I have installed plain Kubernetes with single master cluster configuration. After storing kamel binary into "/usr/local/bin", I was able to run kamel commands. I did the "kamel install --cluster-setup" and the setup is fine. Then when I was trying to run the command "kamel install", I'm getting the following error.

```
root@camelk:~# kamel install
Error: cannot find automatically a registry where to push images
Usage:
  kamel install [flags]

Flags:
      --base-image string          Set the base image used to run integrations
      --build-strategy string      Set the build strategy
      --build-timeout string       Set how long the build process can last
      --camel-version string       Set the camel version
      --cluster-setup              Execute cluster-wide operations only (may require admin rights)
      --context strings            Add a camel context to build at startup, by default all known contexts are built
      --example                    Install example integration
  -h, --help                       help for install
      --local-repository string    Location of the local maven repository
      --maven-repository strings   Add a maven repository
      --maven-settings string      Configure the source of the maven settings (configmap|secret:name[/key])
      --operator-image string      Set the operator image used for the operator deployment
      --organization string        A organization on the Docker registry that can be used to publish images
  -o, --output string              Output format. One of: json|yaml
  -p, --property strings           Add a camel property
      --registry string            A Docker registry that can be used to publish images
      --registry-insecure          Configure to configure registry access in insecure mode or not
      --registry-secret string     A secret used to push/pull images to the Docker registry
      --runtime-version string     Set the camel-k runtime version
      --skip-cluster-setup         Skip the cluster-setup phase
      --skip-operator-setup        Do not install the operator in the namespace (in case there's a global one)
  -w, --wait                       Waits for the platform to be running

Global Flags:
      --config string      Path to the config file to use for CLI requests
  -n, --namespace string   Namespace to use for all operations

Error: cannot find automatically a registry where to push images
```

Could you please help me out here? Have I missed any configurations? I'm in need of help. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the container registry where kamel can pull/push images

For example

```
kamel install --registry=https://index.docker.io/v1/
```